# Does Cross Site Publishing impact the ability to Save Sites as Templates

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, template, cross-site-publishing, save-as-template

It's well knowing that you can't save a publishing site as a template.  The moment you turn on publishing you lose this capability.

Does activating Cross-Site Publishing impact the ability to Save a Site as a Template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you plan to use `Cross-Site Collection Publishing` for Publishing Site,** So

**Yes,** Working with (Not just Activating) the `Cross-Site Collection Publishing` for Publishing Site Will impact the ability to `Save a Site as a Template` functionality.

> **Note**
>
> `Publishing site collections` for the publishing site must have the **SharePoint Server
>   publishing features activated** so you must have
>
> - A `Publishing Site Collection template` (Recommended) or
> - A site collection template that has SharePoint Server publishing features enabled.

**That means** you will **lose** the functionality of `Save Site As
 Template`

[image]

For more details, check [Plan publishing sites for cross-site publishing in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/plan-sharepoint-publishing-sites-for-cross-site-publishing)

---

**If you plan to use `Cross-Site Collection Publishing` for Authoring Site,** So

It depends, if you need Approval workflows and scheduling, you must also activate publishing features that lead to **losing** the functionality of `Save Site As
 Template`.

**Otherwise**, activating `Cross-Site Collection Publishing` feature doesn't impact the ability to `Save a Site as a Template`.

> **Note:** Just activating the `Cross-Site Collection Publishing` doesn't impact the ability to `Save a Site as a Template`
>   functionality in case,
>
> - You don't need to use `Cross-Site Collection Publishing` for a Publishing site.
> - You are using `Cross-Site Collection Publishing` for Authoring site and you **don't** need publishing features like Approval workflows and scheduling.

For more details, check [Plan authoring sites for cross-site publishing in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/plan-sharepoint-authoring-sites-for-cross-site-publishing)

---

**For more details check**

- [Overview of cross-site publishing in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/overview-of-cross-site-publishing)
- [Missing Save Site as a template](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

Comment: Such a shame.  All we want to do is enable the catalog feature on Lists and Libraries via Cross-Site Publishing to display content on different Site Collections via the Content Search Web part.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon thank you for appreciating my answer, kindly, check the update based on your comment :)